# Approximation for the logarithm of a summatory

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, logarithms, approximation

I would like to find an approximation for:

$$
\log \left(\sum_{i=1}^{N} a_i\exp(-b_i^2)\exp(-c_i^2)\right)
$$

with

$$
a_i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(e^2 + e_i^2)(g^2 + g_i^2)}}
\\
b_i = \frac{b-d_i}{2(e^2 + e_i^2)}
\\
c_i = \frac{c-f_i}{2(g^2 + g_i^2)}
$$

where $b, e, c, g$ are floats independent of $i$ and $d_i, e_i, f_i, g_i$ are also floats which depend on $i$. These floats can safely be considered to take random values between $(0,100]$.

Finally $N>1$ and $a_i>0 \,\forall\, i$.

Comment: It depends an incredible amount on the nature of the sequence $b_i^2+c_i^2$.

Comment: @GregMartin ok, I'll expand the question being a bit more precise about those factors.

Comment: There are more names now, but the nature of the sequence is still a mystery.  How are the terms weighted?  Are they all large/small?  Are they larger/smaller when $i$ is larger? etc.  These kinds of qualitative details are what's important.  Could you give a typical example of some $a_i$, $b_i$, and $c_i$?

Comment: @AntonioVargas I've added more info on the floats.